# Hola tengo un ejercicio basico de js que no puedo resolver

Tags: javascript, array

Crear un programa en donde el usuario ingresa numeros y se guardan en un array. Al ingresar "-1" se imprimiran los numeros ingresados junto con sus posiciones dentro del array

mi codigo por ahora lo hice asi:

```
var array = [];
var programa  = prompt ("Inserte un numero: " ,"0");
var resultado = array [programa];
while (programa != -1)
{   
    array.push [programa];
    if (programa == -1)
    {   
        console.log ("Los numeros guardados son: " +array);
    }
}
```

desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Hola ¡ Podrias pasar tu codigo para ver que esta mal y poder ayudarte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya casi lo tienes. La idea es ejecutar el programa repetidas veces hasta que el usuario introduzca `-1`.

Pero en tu bucle `while` no estás preguntando el valor al usuario, lo haces solamente fuera del mismo una única vez. Por otro lado tienes una variable de sobra en tu declaración.

Vamos a entender un poco la lógica de lo que se pide realizar:

> Crear un programa donde:
>
> 1. El usuario ingresa números.
> 2. Las entradas del usuario se almacenan en un `Array`.
> 3. Si el usuario ingresa '-1' se imprimen los valores introducidos junto con el índice de su posición en el `Array`.

Para satisfacer estos 3 requerimientos necesitamos lo siguiente:

1. Una forma de permitir al usuario ingresar los valores.
2. Una variable tipo `Array` para almacenar los valores introducidos.
3. Una forma de identificar (comparar) el valor `-1`.
4. Una forma de repetir el programa hasta que se introduzca el valor '-1'.

Para desarrollar el programa resolveremos todos estos puntos en orden.

**1. Una forma de permitir al usuario ingresar los valores.**

Dado que trabajamos con el navegador, usaremos el método [`prompt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) para solicitar los valores al usuario.

Este método acepta 2 parámetros: El mensaje propiamente dicho (`prompt`) y un valor por defecto (`default`), en caso que el usuario no ingrese ningún valor. El mismo, devuelve un tipo `string` que es el valor introducido por el usuario.

```
var entrada = prompt('Introduzca un valor numérico:', '0');
```

**2. Una variable tipo `Array` para almacenar los valores introducidos.**

Ya tenemos una forma de pedir datos al usuario, ahora vamos a almacenarlos. Para ello crearemos una variable tipo `Array` para poder ir almacenando los valores que el usuario ingrese.

```
var resultado = [];
```

Esto es un `array` vacío, vamos a llenarlo con los valores introducidos por el usuario.

**3. Una forma de identificar (comparar) el valor `-1`.**

Si el usuario ingresa '-1', el programa debe mostrar los valores hasta ahora ingresados junto a su posición en el `Array`.

Usaremos un bloque `if else` para determinar si el usuario ha ingresado '-1'.

```
if(entrada === '-1') {
  // el usuario ha ingresado el valor de fin de programa
} else {
  // seguimos almacenando valores
}
```

**4. Una forma de repetir el programa hasta que se introduzca el valor '-1'.**

Ya tenemos la estructura básica para 1 corrida de nuestro programa, pero debemos repetir el proceso por cada entrada numérica diferente de '-1'.

Usaremos un bucle [`do while`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/do...while). ¿Porqué? Bueno, porque el mismo nos va a permitir correr el programa al menos 1 vez y no tendremos que repetir código fuera del bucle.

```
do {
  //preguntamos el valor
  //decidimos la acción según el valor
} while(true);
```

Puedes observar que he puesto un bucle "infinito", es decir la condición que evaluará `while` es `true`. ¿Cómo detenemos la ejecución de un bucle "infinito"? Pues usaremos una sentencia llamada [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/break), que nos permite terminar el bucle desde la que es llamada.

Con esto tenemos cas todo listo para implementar nuestro programa, solo falta mostrar los valores y su índice.

Para esto contamos con un método de los tipo `Array`: [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach), el cual nos va a permitir iterar sobre el array.

El método `forEach()` puede recibir hasta 3 parámetros, pero realmente nos interesan 2 de ellos: el elemento que estamos iterando y el índice del mismo.

Esto es muy conveniente, ya que así tenemos directamente los valores que buscamos y sólo debemos mostrarlos por pantalla.

**El código por favor**

Ahora como buenos albañiles, pondremos todos los bloques juntos y construiremos un programa:

```js
var resultado = [];

do {
  var entrada = prompt('Introduzca un valor numérico:','0');
  if(entrada === '-1') {
    // el bucle debe terminar
    break;
  } else {
    resultado.push(entrada);
  }
} while(true);

resultado.forEach((element, index) => {
  console.log('Entrada: ', element, ', índice: ', index);
});
```

**Nota**

En esta implementación no se está validando que el usuario efectivamente ingrese un valor numérico.

Para hacerlo podemos usar el método [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/parseInt) junto con el método [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/isNaN).

El primero analiza un string y lo convierte en su representación numérica de ser posible, si no es posible devuelve un valor [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/NaN).

El segundo analiza si un valor es tipo `NaN` o no, y devuelve `true` o `false` según sea el caso.

**El código con validación**

```js
var resultado = [];

do {
  var entrada = prompt('Introduzca un valor numérico:','0');
  if(entrada === '-1') {
    // el bucle debe terminar
    break;
  } else {
    // verificamos si el valor introducido es numérico o no
    if(!isNaN(parseInt(entrada))) {
      // si es numérico lo guardamos
      // si no lo es, será descartado
      resultado.push(entrada);
    }
  }
} while(true);

resultado.forEach((element, index) => {
  console.log('Entrada: ', element, ', índice: ', index);
});
```

Con esto ya tienes el programa funcionando, espero que te ayude a aclarar dudas.